# Combine multiple matrices and apply percent and parentheses formats

Tags: r, matrix, r-markdown

I'm trying to create this matrix in RMarkdown.

[image]

I tried using the following code but when I `cbind` the `%` and `()` formats are removed:

```
# put matrices together
m <- matrix(rbind(t(pij), t(se_pij)), ncol = ncol(pij), byrow = T)
m <- percent(m[1:6,1:3])
m[c(2,4,6),] <- matrix(paste0("(", format(unlist(m[c(2,4,6), 1:3])),")"), nrow = 3, byrow = FALSE)

blank <- c("", "", "")
obs <- matrix(rbind(t(nij), t(blank)), ncol = 1, byrow = T)
obs <- apply(obs , 2, as.numeric)
m <- cbind(m, obs)

blank <- c("", "", "")
obs <- matrix(rbind(t(nij), t(blank)), ncol = 1, byrow = T)
obs <- apply(obs , 2, as.numeric)
m <- cbind(m, obs)
```

My data:

```
nij <- c(Downgraded = 811, Unchanged = 983, Upgraded = 841)

pij <- structure(c(0.168927250308261, 0.32146490335707, 0.454221165279429, 
0.274969173859433, 0.458799593082401, 0.392390011890606, 0.556103575832306, 
0.219735503560529, 0.153388822829964), class = "table", .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Downgraded", "Unchanged", "Upgraded"
), j = c("Downgraded", "Unchanged", "Upgraded")))

se_pij <- structure(c(0.0131570628879201, 0.014896223560517, 0.0171689616489814, 
0.0156786914420421, 0.0158932900891351, 0.0168373378492297, 0.0174464969960683, 
0.0132066990320836, 0.0124262720735792), class = "table", .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Downgraded", "Unchanged", "Upgraded"
), j = c("Downgraded", "Unchanged", "Upgraded")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `percent()` is from the package `scales` you could use the function directly in the matrix generation.

```
m <- matrix(scales::percent(rbind(t(pij), t(se_pij)), accuracy=0.01), ncol = ncol(pij), byrow = T)
m[c(2,4,6),] <- matrix(paste0("(", format(unlist(m[c(2,4,6), 1:3])),")"), nrow = 3, byrow = FALSE)

blank <- c("", "", "")
obs <- matrix(rbind(t(nij), t(blank)), ncol = 1, byrow = T)
obs <- apply(obs , 2, as.numeric)
m <- cbind(m, obs)
m

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] 
[1,] "16.89%"  "27.50%"  "55.61%"  "811"
[2,] "(1.32%)" "(1.57%)" "(1.74%)" NA   
[3,] "32.15%"  "45.88%"  "21.97%"  "983"
[4,] "(1.49%)" "(1.59%)" "(1.32%)" NA   
[5,] "45.42%"  "39.24%"  "15.34%"  "841"
[6,] "(1.72%)" "(1.68%)" "(1.24%)" NA
```